# stackoverflow badges meaning

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

What's the meaning of:

1. First retag
2. Strunk & White :  Edited 100 entries
3. Peer Pressure
4. First flagged post

I'm a chinese man ,and i don't know the meaning very well.

thanks

Comment: Damn it's annoying to write out a full answer to a question, only to be informed that the question has been closed as a duplicate.